# comment system using ajax with laravel without reloaded page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel, comments

I want to add a comment system on my website using AJAX with Laravel to load new comments without refreshing whole page.

I always have this error :

> Ajax Post 500 (Internal Server Error)

below is my code:

```
view page :
{!! Form::open(array('action' => array('PersonsController@newComment', $person->id))) !!}          
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('name', 'Nom ') !!}
{!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' =>'form-control', 'style'=>'border-radius: 0']) !!}
</div>  

<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('mail', 'E-mail ') !!}
{!! Form::text('mail', null, ['class' =>'form-control', 'style'=>'border-radius: 0']) !!}
</div>  

<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('comment', 'Contenu ') !!}
{!! Form::textarea('comment', null, ['class' =>'form-control', 'style'=>'border-radius: 0']) !!}
</div>  

<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::submit('Publier', array('class'=>'send-btn')) !!}               
</div>  
{!! Form::close() !!}

route page :

Route::get('{id}/apropos','PersonsController@show');
Route::post('{id}/apropos','PersonsController@newComment');
```

Controller page :

```
public function newComment($id) {
    if ($request::ajax()) {
        $name = Input::get('name');
        $mail = Input::get('mail');
        $comment = Input::get('comment');
        $Comments = new \App\Comment;

        $Comments->Persons_id = $id;
        $Comments->date = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
        $Comments->name=$name;
        $Comments->mail=$mail;
        $Comments->comment=$comment;
        $Comments->save();

        $reponse =array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'msg' => 'Setting created successfully',
        );

        return \Response::json($response);
    } else {
        return 'no';
    }
}
```

Ajax page :

```
$.ajaxSetup({  
   headers: {  
           'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')  
    } 
});      

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.send-btn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var mail = $('#mail').val();
        var comment = $('#comment').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '{{url("1/apropos")}}',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {name: name, mail: mail, comment: comment},
            success: function( data ) {
            $("body").append("<div>"+data+"</div>");                
            }
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: Do you have access to the error log? That would give us a better idea of where the problem lies if you add it to your question. 500 error could mean anything as far as critical errors go.

Comment: how can I see it? one of :..storage\logs\laraval.log

Comment: If using Apache, find out where your Apache conf is dumping the logs for this project and you should see it there

Comment: below the last error in the log file in apache 
::1 - - [10/Aug/2016:18:49:23 +0200] "POST /doc/public/1/apropos HTTP/1.1" 500 26002

Comment: That is from the access log. There should also be an error log being output as well.

Comment: please, where I can find the apache LogLevel file in windws 7?

Comment: I do not know if you mean this file ErrorLog "c:/wamp/logs/apache_error.log" because the file is not updating its last update July!  I found the file path in httpd.config

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your ajax page is in the same page than the view (because you are using .send-btn).

It´s easier to use $.post() because you don´t need to configure so many parameters. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Do you have more information about the error:  Ajax Post 500 (Internal Server Error). Don´t you have any message? Use error function on $.ajax:

> error callback option is invoked, if the request fails. It receives
>   the jqXHR, a string indicating the error type, and an exception object
>   if applicable. Some built-in errors will provide a string as the
>   exception object: "abort", "timeout", "No Transport".

so you can add at your AJAX request something like:

```
error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
    console.log(xhr.status);
    console.log(xhr.statusText);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(thrownError);
  }
```

Comment: I dont have more information about error : POST http://localhost:82/doc/public/1/apropos 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-2.1.0.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-2.1.0.min.js:4
(anonymous function) @ apropos:1002
dispatch @ jquery-2.1.0.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery-2.1.0.min.js:3

how I can use : $.post()

Comment: below the last error in the log file in apache 
::1 - - [10/Aug/2016:18:49:23 +0200] "POST /doc/public/1/apropos HTTP/1.1" 500 26002

Comment: I found the issue, it is an email field doubling, it was a single field (UNIQUE)!!!